# Download data sets from Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, dataset

I want to know if it is possible to download a portion of a public AWS data set and how to do it.

Specifically, I want to download a part from [Common Crawl Corpus](http://aws.amazon.com/datasets/41740) to do local tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can. If you point your browser to the [public URL provided by Amazon](http://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-publicdatasets/), you can see links for the whole sets and also for subsets.

You can download it using your browser or any S3 client tools or libraries.

Comment: Thank you. I could download a sample.

Comment: Is there any data available for card transactions?